# LinkButtons stop working when I add JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, linkbutton

I have a problem making my LinkButtons work with JavaScripts.

When I remove the references to the JavaScript files, the click events on my Linkbuttons work fine.

But when I put back the references to the JavaScript files, the LinkButtons stop working. I am also using ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console? Try Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug in Firefox

Comment: post your linkbutton code & any JS that affects them.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this myself. Check for errors in your script. Also check the output and make sure the scripts are attached (I saw a UserControl not attach the doPostback code to a gridview).

You can also include the references and comment out method by method to find the one causing the problem. It's brute force, but sometimes you've got no choice.

Also check your ScriptMode in the ScriptManager. I use Release all the time (otherwise I get strange behavior when I'm debugging).